# Авторизация в VK через HTTP-запрос к API

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, vkontakte-api, http, httpwebrequest

При попытке провести авторизацию через запрос к API VK получаю от сервера код 401.

В связи с тем, что нужно использовать определённые user-агенты, от использования библиотек – отказался.

```
MainWindow main = new MainWindow();

var client_id = 123456;
var client_secret = "qwerty";
var AudioBotVk = new HttpClient();
//WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy(main.ProxyBox.ToString(), true);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    "https://oauth.vk.com/token?scope=nohttps%2Call&client_id="
    + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret
    + "&2fa_supported=1&lang=ru&grant_type=password&username="
    + main.LoginBox.Text.ToString() + "&password=" + main.PasswordBox.ToString()
    + "&libverify_support=1");

request.Method = "GET";
request.Host = "oauth.vk.com";
request.UserAgent = "Foo/bar (param1; param2; param3; param4; ru)";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


HttpWebResponse responsevk = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Что это _`Foo/bar (param1; param2; param3; param4; ru)`_?

Comment: @AGS17 юзер агент,у себя в коде использую другой.
на авторизацию он не влияет.

Comment: К слову, _от использования либ - отказался_ - почему?

Comment: @AGS17 в либах нельзя задавать свой Юзер-агент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот с таким кодом,авторизация прошла.

```
 public static void VkAuth1()
    {
        var login = "логин";
        var password = "пароль";

        var Vk = new HttpClient();
        Vk.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "close");

        string url = string.Format("https://oauth.vk.com/token?scope=nohttps%2Call
&client_id=123456&client_secret=qwertyu&2fa_supported=1&lang=ru
&device_id=123456789def&grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}&libverify_support=1", 
login, password);


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Host = "oauth.vk.com";
        request.UserAgent = "qwert";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        using (HttpWebResponse responsevk = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = responsevk.GetResponseStream())
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadToEnd());

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [VK.NET](https://vknet.github.io/vk/). 
Пример авторизации:

```
int appID = 12345;                      // ID приложения
string email = "test@test.com";         // email или телефон
string pass = "password";               // пароль для авторизации
Settings scope = Settings.Friends;      // Приложение имеет доступ кдрузьям

var vk = new VkApi();
vk.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams)
{
  ApplicationId = (ulong)appID,
  Login = email,
  Password = pass,
  Settings = scope
};
```

Comment: _от использования либ - отказался_

Comment: ну тогда как вариант откомпилить исходники со своим user-agent

Comment: Читайте в следующий раз вопрос внимательнее.